# Using Grease Pencil to make the projection painting of a real Photo on a 2D plane

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, grease-pencil

Since I've read that the drawings created with grease pencil are objects,I would like to know if I can make the project painting of a new face over the actor's face that I have mapped as an image on a 2D plane. I have 1600 images for which I want to make the same. Let's say that it is one of the picture for which I want to alter the face features :

[image: 1]

It comes from a movie,so I can't use it as is. The face should be altered. But the rest of the picture can be the same to save time. This is the texture of the face that i want to use :

[image: 2]

It should cover perfectly the original face. I could use a 3D model of the head,but I think that posing the 3D characters exactly over a 2D image is not exactly easy and it takes much more time,so I would like to try to make the projection painting of the texture over the 2D plane. Below you can see that I have mapped the picture over the plane :

[image: 3]

I don't know if I should use grease pencil to draw the face border's or if it is enough to make a lot of subdivisions on the plane. For sure I want that the new face will fit perfectly over the original one. Let me know if I can do it and how. thanks.